# Python Pandas: Reindex DataFrame after Timezone conversion

Tags: python, pandas

Lets consider the following DataFrame spanning 10am to 4pm on Jan 16:

```
date_range1 = pd.date_range(dt(2017,1,16,10), dt(2017,1,16, 20), freq='2H')
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(len(date_range1),2), index = date_range1)
```

I reindex it with a slightly longer DateTimeindex spanning 0am to 11pm and obtain the desired result, with NaNs filling the time range between 0-10am and 4-11pm where there is no data:

```
date_range2 = pd.date_range(dt(2017,1,16,0), dt(2017,1,16, 23), freq='2H')
df.reindex(date_range2)
```

[image]

However if I modify the timezone of `df` first, then doing the same reindex operation yield a DataFrame completely filled with NaNs values:

```
df = df.tz_localize("Europe/Helsinki").tz_convert('UTC')  
df.reindex(date_range2)
```

[image]

Anyone has any idea what is happening here?

Comment: this looks like a bug to me, the new index is time-zone aware but it's utc so it should be able to handle any datetime indexing, I'd post a bug on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: not a bug; UTC is not the same as naive at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Fix:***

One workaround would be to get rid of the timezone information from timezone-aware (`tz`) `DateTimeIndex` after converting to UTC time using `tz_convert(None)` so that the difference in them (Here, `UTC+02:00`) gets added to the resulting timestamps.

Then, these would reindex properly.

```
np.random.seed(42)
df1 = df.tz_localize("Europe/Helsinki").tz_convert('UTC').tz_localize(None)
df1.reindex(date_range2)
```

[image]

---

***Right approach:***

By default, the `tz` keyword argument in `pd.date_range` is `None` and not `"UTC"`. We need to change this accordingly as underneath the reindexing happens by comparing their UTC timestamps:

```
date_range2.tz = 'UTC'
df1 = df.tz_localize("Europe/Helsinki").tz_convert('UTC')
df1.reindex(date_range2)
```

[image]